# Batch script to delete Computer Objects from the ARS portal

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I used the below script to delete bulk users from the ARS portal [Dell Active Roles]

```
Connect-QADService  -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential)
Import-Csv "C:\IT\DeleteUser.csv" | foreach{Remove-QADObject $_.UserPrincipalName}
```

I have modified the above script like in below to remove computer objects but it gives the below error.

```
@echo off
powershell.exe Connect-QADService  -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential) Import-Csv "C:\IT\Computer.csv" | foreach{Remove-QADObject $_.HostName}
```

Is it possible to eliminate the prompt for credentials from the above command?

### Error:

```
PS C:\> Connect-QADService  -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential) Import-Csv "C:\IT\Computers.csv" | foreach{Remove-QADComputer $_.HostName}

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
Connect-QADService : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\IT\Computers.csv'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-QADService  -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential) Import-Csv "C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Connect-QADService], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,ActiveRoles.ManagementShell.Commands.ConnectCmdlet
```

### Error while changing it to ADComputer:

```
PS C:\> Connect-QADService  -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential) Import-Csv "C:\IT\Computers.csv" | foreach{Remove-ADComputer $_.HostName}

cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
Connect-QADService : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\IT\Computers.csv'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-QADService  -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential) Import-Csv "C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Connect-QADService], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,ActiveRoles.ManagementShell.Commands.ConnectCmdlet
```

### Computers.csv contains

```
Hostname
A00001
A00002
A00003
B00001
C01241
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the command `import-csv` in the middle of the call to `Connect-QADService`. Note how all of the other parameters have been passed in with a `-` e.g. `-proxy`

I doubt the command `Connect-QADService` has a parameter of `-import-csv`

You want the Connect, and the import commands to be seperated. If you need it all in one line and running from CMD for what ever reason, try this:

```
@echo off 
powershell.exe "Connect-QADService -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential); Import-Csv 'C:\IT\Computer.csv' | foreach { Remove-QADObject $_.HostName }"
```

(note the semi-colon depicting the end of the `Connect-QADService` command before we run the import)

Comment: The above command is working but is waiting for our input prior to deleting each hostname like in below

Warning!
Are you sure you want to delete this object:
CN=A015683,OU=ABC,OU=Cdef,OU=Stuvw,OU=Resources,DC=hijkl,DC=pqr?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y

Is there any way to avoid prompting for the credentials too?

Comment: Yes the `Remove` verb commands usually have a `-confirm:` parameter that you can pass in. Have a look at the documentation for the command

Answer (score 0):

@echo off
powershell.exe "Connect-QADService -Proxy -Credential (Get-Credential); Import-Csv 'C:\IT\Computer.csv' | foreach { Remove-QADObject $_.HostName -force }"